# How to set the backcolor of DevExpress VerticalGrid's new record in InitNewRecord eventhandler

Tags: devexpress

When invoking the VerticalGrid's **AddNewRecord** method,  the `InitNewRecord` event fires. In that eventhandler, how would you set the backcolor of the new record that is being added? The Vertical Grid is in MultiRecord mode.

Comment: Is your vgrid bound or unbound, and if bound, to what?

Comment: It is bound to a DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [RecordCellStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraVerticalGridVGridControlBase_RecordCellStyletopic) event to color a new added row. In the [InitNewRecord](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraVerticalGridVGridControlBase_InitNewRecordtopic) event, you can obtain a new row index and store it, for example, in a list of new rows. Then in the RecordCellStyle event, check if the event is raised for a new row and provide that row with the required appearance.

```
List<object> newRows = new List<object>();
private void vGridControl1_InitNewRecord(object sender, DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Events.RecordIndexEventArgs e) {
    VGridControl grid = (VGridControl)sender;
    object item = grid.GetRecordObject(e.RecordIndex);
    newRows.Add(item);
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { grid.UpdateFocusedRecord(); }));
}

private void vGridControl1_RecordCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Events.GetCustomRowCellStyleEventArgs e) {
    VGridControl grid = (VGridControl)sender;
    if(newRows.Contains(grid.GetRecordObject(e.RecordIndex)))
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I hadn't thought of keeping a separate cache of added rows.